# C# Multithreading - Executing same method concurrently in 100 Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker, threadpool

I have a class method that i am trying to execute concurrently in almost 100 threads. This method is basically about HTTPWebRequests and database R/W
My application is a console application which spins up threads to call this method.

Now when i dont thread and run 35-45 copies or instance of my console application, i get a faster/better performance, however when i run 100 threads, the performance drops by as much as 50%.

I have tried threadpool, array of background workers, threads and even tasks, but something is not working the way it should. This is how i am invoking a static method in main class that in turn class the other class method.

```
            while (flagProcess)
        {
            if (RAMPRead.CheckJobQueue())
            {


                bool allThreadsinUse = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < ts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (ts[i] == null || ts[i].ThreadState != ThreadState.Running)
                    {
                        ts[i] = new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            RAMPit(session);
                        });
                        ts[i].Start();
                        ts[i].IsBackground = true;
                        allThreadsinUse = false;
                        while (!ts[i].IsAlive) { }
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                }
                if (!allThreadsinUse)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    MemoryManagement.FlushMemory();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                MemoryManagement.FlushMemory();
            }
        }

        private static void RAMPit(object s)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Session outsession = new Session();
        _sem.Wait();
        using (z z = new z("user", "pass"))
        {
            outsession = z.ProcessNext((Session)s, "user", "pass");
            session = outsession;
        }
        _sem.Release();
        MemoryManagement.FlushMemory();
        //return result;
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here OR how can i get to run many threads concurrently for faster output.

Comment: Do you have 100 cores in your CPU?

Comment: You shouldn't be using *anywhere near* 100 threads unless you're on a massively expensive machine. A good rule of thumb is the number of cores on in your CPU. Alternatively, you can use `Parallel.ForEach()` which will do a very good job at managing the number of threads needed

Comment: Thank you @Rob, If i dont multithread i am able to easily run 30-35 instance s of my console app, but switching to multithreading and trying to do the same thing with 40 threads doesnt work with same efficiency. I get your point about max threads relative to core. i appreciate your help

Comment: @user1548923 It depends entirely on how you're managing threads. Things like `Thread.Sleep(10000);` and forcing the garbage collection don't seem ideal (especially the sleep). Try using `Parallel.ForEach`. If you were to have a list of URLs, for example, you'd do something like this: `Parallel.ForEach(urls, url => { Process(url); })` with nothing else. Give that a whirl and let us know how it goes

Comment: It is not a coding solution, because it will not be solve your problem. Overclock your CPU. Lol.

Comment: @Rob Thanks, I am trying Parallel.ForEach now, testing with it.

Comment: Parallel.ForEach is giving the same kind of results that threads threadpool and background workers did

Comment: If you still use `GC` in loop and `Thread.Sleep` your app can not be improved

Comment: If your CPU is pegged at 100%, you have enough threads. Any more is just adding overhead for no gain.

Comment: You need to determine what is throttling throughput. Is it I/O bound waiting for the HTTP traffic, is it database contention, CPU, memory, ... . Once you can measure the problem you can work on fixing it and tell what progress you're making. And there's something that just nags about the "spin wait while it's dead" (`while (!ts[i].IsAlive) { }`).